# Redhat Nodejs-minimal yarn not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, node.js

Coming across a very odd issue here:

Whenever I try using a ubi8/nodejs-14-minimal base image, the build fails with /bin/sh: yarn not found.

I have installed yarn already by adding a Run npm install yarn -- global layer on my dockerfile. The same doesn't happens with a way mic more stripped down base image, such as ubi-minimal. I add the nodejs 14 module, and it works just fine when calling npm install yarn -- global.

Are you guys experienced with these RH ubi images? Has anyone ever stumbled on such a similar issue?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65926128/yarn-command-not-found-after-installing-via-npm (of which the `$PATH` direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/69655971/239657 sounds promising)